# Save NSDate in core data XCode 5.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to save NSDate in core data model.
for example I want to store value for 'birthDate' in model 'User'.

Any help?

Comment: Where is the problem? Create an attribute of type "Date" in the model inspector and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the attribute and change its type to date

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As @inder and Martin Create an attribute of type "Date" in the model inspector
and store it using,

```
NSDateFormatter *dt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]; // for example
NSDate *bdate = [dt dateFromString:@"2012-10-15"];
[Sets setValue:bdate forKey:@"birthDate"];
```